# Combining list in python with condition

Tags: python, list

I have two lists as shown below:

```
  user_list = ['oshamir','oshamir','oshamir','ctmuser','ctmuser','root','root','root']

  num_list =  ['400','700','600','300','500','1000','400','2000']
```

I would like to combine a list with the condition that will take the max num for each user so finally I will get this list

```
[['oshamir','700'],['ctmuser','500'],['root','2000']]
```

any suggestions?

TNX

Comment: Could you please clarify your question. What does "the max num for each user" mean?

Comment: Is the user list always sorted by the user name? Does the order of `user_list` need to be preserved in the result?

Comment: First change the strings to numbers in the `num_list`. Second combine the data: `combined = list(zip(user_list, num_list))`. Then keep working. (Hint: `data = dict(sorted(combined))` could be the next step).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `zip` to pair the lists up, then group pairs by user and from each group pick the one with max value:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> user_list = ['oshamir','oshamir','oshamir','ctmuser','ctmuser','root','root','root']
>>> num_list =  ['400','700','600','300','500','1000','400','2000']
>>> [max(g, key=lambda x: int(x[1])) for _, g in groupby(zip(user_list, num_list), lambda x: x[0])]
[('oshamir', '700'), ('ctmuser', '500'), ('root', '2000')]
```

In above [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) returns iterable of `(user, num)` tuples:

```
>>> pairs = list(zip(user_list, num_list))
>>> pairs
[('oshamir', '400'), ('oshamir', '700'), ('oshamir', '600'), ('ctmuser', '300'), ('ctmuser', '500'), ('root', '1000'), ('root', '400'), ('root', '2000')]
```

Then [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) is used to group the items based on the first item in each tuple:

```
>>> groups = [list(g) for _, g in groupby(pairs, lambda x: x[0])]
>>> groups
[[('oshamir', '400'), ('oshamir', '700'), ('oshamir', '600')], [('ctmuser', '300'), ('ctmuser', '500')], [('root', '1000'), ('root', '400'), ('root', '2000')]]
```

Finally [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) with `key` function is used to pick the pair with maximum value. Note that the items on `num_list` are strings so they need to be converted to numbers so that we pick `'2000'` instead of `'400'`:

```
>>> [max(g, key=lambda x: int(x[1])) for g in groups]
[('oshamir', '700'), ('ctmuser', '500'), ('root', '2000')]
```

Answer (score 0):

If order matters, you can use an `OrderedDict`, otherwise, a normal `dict` will do. But basically, use one pass to make a mapping from user to num, keeping the larger value each time. Then, another pass to get the data-structure you want.

```
>>> d = OrderedDict()
>>> for user, num in zip(user_list, num_list):
...     d[user] = max(d.get(user, float('-inf')), int(num))
...
>>> [[k,v] for k,v in d.items()]
[['oshamir', 700], ['ctmuser', 500], ['root', 2000]]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

The sorting that you require needs numbers not strings. A different result is returned when sorting the numbers as strings.

```
res = list(zip(user_list, map(int, num_list)))  # [('oshamir', 400), ('oshamir', 700), ('oshamir', 600), ('ctmuser', 300), ('ctmuser', 500), ('root', 1000), ('root', 400), ('root', 2000)]
res.sort(key=lambda x: (x[0], x[1]))            # [('ctmuser', 300), ('ctmuser', 500), ('oshamir', 400), ('oshamir', 600), ('oshamir', 700), ('root', 400), ('root', 1000), ('root', 2000)]
final = {k:str(v) for k,v in res}               # {'ctmuser': '500', 'root': '2000', 'oshamir': '700'}
```

So I would convert to numbers, sort and get the max and finally switch back to strings.

if you explicitly require a list of lists as the output you can add a list comprehension on top like so:

```
final = [[a, b] for a, b in final.items()]      # [['ctmuser', '500'], ['root', '2000'], ['oshamir', '700']]
```